# add 'file upload' field to user details

Tags: users, uploads, profiles

In the backend when a user goes to their detail page they can edit a few text fields. I want to add a custom field that allows the user to upload a file. I found something similar but its only to add extra text fields.

[add extra user fields](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/adding-extra-fields-to-the-wordpress-user-profile/m)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) which will allow you to add as many fields as you'd like and currently supports:

- text
- textarea
- textarea-rich
- password
- checkbox
- radio
- drop-down
- picture
- picture-url
- registration-date
- avatar
- **file**