# Photo gallery on profile page?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, profiles, plugin-members

Is there a way, (or a plugin), that allows members to have their own photos on their profile page? I want to limit the amount of photos to perhaps 50. Any suggestions??? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Bump... Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

> While answering this Q, stumbled upon this other one: [add 'file upload' field to user details](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16426/12615), which may be a duplicate and where Bainternet suggests [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/).

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) can do the job.

Without any premium Add-on* this can be solved adding Image fields to the Users pages:
[image]

<sup>^^^^</sup>
Which results in this:
[image: acf result]

---

`*` http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/
The Repeatable Fields would make this less cumbersome. And just learned that there's a new add-on: Gallery, that seems quite interesting for managing images.
But, in those cases, I guess you'll have to create some jQuery to control the maximum allowed pictures.

---

You'll probably need/would-like to restrict the access to other users uploaded files.
See: [How to hide media uploads by other users in the Media menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/30308/12615).