# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin: how would I get an image src path uploaded from User Profile?

Tags: users, advanced-custom-fields

I have created an Image Upload field for a User Photo in the User Profile section in the wp-admin using Advanced Custom Fields. I realized ACF could do this per this post: [Photo gallery on profile page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43997/photo-gallery-on-profile-page)

How would I go about capturing the contents of the image src field in ACF? The following does not work:

```
<?php $publisher_photo = get_field('user_photo'); ?>

<?php echo "<img class='publisher-picture' src='$publisher_photo' />"; ?>
```

I even tried this, but it does not work either:

```
<?php $publisher_photo = get_the_author_meta('user_photo'); ?>
<?php echo "<img class='publisher-picture' src='$publisher_photo' />"; ?>
```

When I try to debug and echo the contents of the $publisher_photo variable, it comes back blank leading me to believe I'm not picking up this field from the User Profile in the correct way.

Comment: In addition, when I do some debugging, such as: <? php echo $publisher_photo; ?> This is not returning anything. The variable appears to be blank.

Comment: Thanks for this bit of code. Has worked perfectly... However do you know why it is cropping the image to 150px x 150px? Is it possible to display the original size? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! Here's what solved my problem:

```
<?php
$publisher_photo = get_the_author_meta('user_photo');
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($publisher_photo);
echo '<img class="publisher-picture" src="'. $image_src[0] .'" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not reading your variable $publisher_photo. Try `<?php echo '<img class="publisher-picture" src="'. $publisher_photo .'" />'; ?>`

Comment: That didn't work for me..Still shows up blank in the view.